# ¿como obtener datos de tabla Bootstrap de las columnas visibles?

Tags: c#, json, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc, google-chart-api

tengo una tabla que tiene la extencion resize desabilito algunas columnas y uso el metodo `$table.bootstrapTable('getData')` quiero obtener una JSon con las columnas que quedan pero el metodo trae todas las columnas. como seria para traer solo las columnas visibles. luego pasarlo A google Chart.
table bootstrap:http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html

```
    <table id="table"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-url="/Admin/ListSelect"
       data-show-export="true"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-resizable="true"
       data-click-to-select="true"
       data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       data-height="480"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-search="true"
       data-flat="true"
       data-show-multi-sort="true"
       data-sort-priority='[{"sortName": "Nombre","sortOrder":"desc"},{"sortName":"Focus","sortOrder":"desc"}]'
       data-filter-control="true"
       data-filter-show-clear="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var aa in new AuxAudit().GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                <th data-field= @aa.Name data-sortable="true"> @aa.Name</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<button id="button" class="btn btn-default">getData</button>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadChart() {
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
}


function drawChart() {

    var jsonData = JSON.stringify($('#table').bootstrapTable('getData'));
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);


    var options = {'title':'Auditoria',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

De la documentación oficial

getData:

> Retorna los datos cargados en la tabla en el momento que se llama este método. Si se setea useCurrentPage a true se devolverá los datos mostrados en la página actual.

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/es/documentation/